# Using markdown-loader on react page to render markdown file. Getting data:text/x-markdown;base64,IyMgRHVkZQ== instead of rendered file

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I'm using markdown-loader in react to load in a markdown file and display it on a page.

I get no errors but the page doesn't show my markdown file. Instead this is displayed where the file should be:

data:text/x-markdown;base64,IyMgRHVkZQ==

I've tried a few different methods but always end up with this. I'm not sure what this is or how to go about addressing it, as I'm pretty new to this. Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';

import markdownFile from '../markdown/test.md';

const TestComponent = React.createClass({
  rawMarkup(){
         return{ __html: markdownFile};
  },
  render(){
         return(
           <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()} />
          );
 }
});    

const BlogPost1 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
            <TestComponent />
    );
  }
});

export default BlogPost1;
```

This is my whole webpack.config.dev.js file:

```js
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
var InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
var WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
var getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
var paths = require('./paths');



// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
var publicPath = '/';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
var publicUrl = '';
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
var env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// This is the development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience and fast rebuilds.
// The production configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  // You may want 'eval' instead if you prefer to see the compiled output in DevTools.
  // See the discussion in https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/343.
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  // These are the "entry points" to our application.
  // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
  // The first two entry points enable "hot" CSS and auto-refreshes for JS.
  entry: [
    // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
    // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
    // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
    // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
    // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
    // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
    // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
    // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
    // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    // We ship a few polyfills by default:
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    // Finally, this is your app's code:
    paths.appIndexJs
    // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
    // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
  ],
  output: {
    // Next line is not used in dev but WebpackDevServer crashes without it:
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    pathinfo: true,
    // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
    // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    // This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
    publicPath: publicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We read `NODE_PATH` environment variable in `paths.js` and pass paths here.
    // We use `fallback` instead of `root` because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    fallback: paths.nodePaths,
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', ''],
    alias: {
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web'
    }
  },
  
  module: {
    // First, run the linter.
    // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: paths.appSrc,
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      // Default loader: load all assets that are not handled
      // by other loaders with the url loader.
      // Note: This list needs to be updated with every change of extensions
      // the other loaders match.
      // E.g., when adding a loader for a new supported file extension,
      // we need to add the supported extension to this loader too.
      // Add one new line in `exclude` for each loader.
      //
      // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
      // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
      // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
      // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
      // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
      // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
      {
        exclude: [
          /\.html$/,
          /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          /\.css$/,
          /\.json$/,
          /\.svg$/,
          /\.scss$/,
          /\.md$/,
        ],
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      },
      // Process Markdown
      { test: /\.md$/, 
        loader: "html!markdown?gfm=false" 
      },
      // Process SCSS.
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
      },
      // Process JS with Babel.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          
          // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
          // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
          // directory for faster rebuilds.
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      },
      // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
      // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
      // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
      // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
      // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss'
      },
      // JSON is not enabled by default in Webpack but both Node and Browserify
      // allow it implicitly so we also enable it.
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      // "file" loader for svg
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'file',
        query: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  
  // We use PostCSS for autoprefixing only.
  postcss: function() {
    return [
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: [
          '>1%',
          'last 4 versions',
          'Firefox ESR',
          'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
        ]
      }),
    ];
  },
  plugins: [
    // Makes the public URL available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In development, this will be an empty string.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
      PUBLIC_URL: publicUrl
    }),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env),
    // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
    // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/240
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
    // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
    // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/186
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules)
  ],
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your markdown will be rendered if you pass something like below ?

```
return{ __html: 'test'}; // instead of return { __html: markdownFile};
```

If it works, check if you have installed `html-loader` and `file-loader` in your package.json to make render your imported file.

I recommend to use es6 classes in your code. You're using const, so you can do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import markdownFile from '../markdown/test.md';

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {  
    rawMarkup(){
           return{ __html: markdownFile};
    }
    render(){
           return(
             <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()} />
            );
   }
}
export default class BlogPost1 extends React.Component {  
    render(){
           return(
             <TestComponent />
            );
   }
}
```

Comment: `return{ __html: 'test'};` works just fine and renders the text normally.

I do have `html-loader` and `file-loader` installed from my package.json file, do I have to require them at the beginning of my webpack config file? If so, the tutorial I was running from skipped that step.

Comment: @Zach look here https://github.com/peerigon/markdown-loader and check example. Including loaders at the top of your webpack config file is not required, but you can try parse your file to html by require("marked") module. You should include html-loader into your module loader. Look at the example from github. Are you using webpack 2 or 1 version ?

Comment: I'm using webpack 1.14.0 that came along with create-react-app. I've looked at that example and as far as I can tell, I've included everything correctly.

Comment: Could you add your complete webpack config file?

Comment: Sure, I added it up top